# Expected number of copies of graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G\subset K_n$ be a subgraph of the complete graph and let $v(G)$ and $e(G)$ denote its vertex and edge set, respectively. Consider the Bernoulli graph $\mathcal G = \mathcal G(|v(G)|, p)$ on $|v(G)|$ many vertices and with edge probability $p$.

> What is the expected number of copies of $G$ in $\mathcal G$?

To obtain an induced copy of $G$ we need to successfully pick $|e(G)|$ particular edges and fail to pick the remaining ${|v(G)| \choose 2} - |e(G)|$ ones. So the expectation must look something like:

$$M \cdot p^{|e(G)|} \cdot (1-p)^{{|v(G)| \choose 2} - |e(G)|}$$

where $M$ is the number of possible ways of arranging a copy in $G$. But what form does $M$ take exactly? I can't seem to figure it out and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Isn't $M$ just $|v(G)|!$ divided by the order of the automorphism group of $G$? By the way why do you mention $K_n$ in your question? What does $n$ have to do with anything? It's just some arbitrary integer $\ge|v(G)|$, isn't it? And it's not mentioned again?

Comment: Important details : does $G$ has to be **induced** ? It's not said in your question, while it is in your tentative answer.

Comment: Ah @ThomasLesgourgues yees, $G$ has to be induced! Sorry for missing that important detail.

Comment: @bof Could you elaborate why it would be $|v(G)|!$ divided by the order of the automorphism group of $G$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of house subgraphs in a Erdős-Rényi graph?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885204/number-of-house-subgraphs-in-a-erd%c5%91s-r%c3%a9nyi-graph)